# Xampp Error 324 Empty Response when using XDebug

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug

I have a problem with XDebug. I have a XAMPP Server in Version 1.6.6a with PHP 5.2.5 installed. I downloaded xdebug in Version 2.2.7 (*php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.2-vc9.dll*) and placed it into the ext folder and added it to the php.ini

```
zend_extension_ts = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.7-5.2-vc9.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

My problem is that when I add xdebug to my php.ini it will cause an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when I try to call a php Demo like http://localhost/xampp/phonebook.php . I don't know why the error is thrown because I can call the http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php and it will execute correctly.

Why do I get an empty response ?

The phpinfo shows me

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend Extension Manager v1.2.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2007, by Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans

So I assume that xdebug is correctly installed.

I have to use this old version of xampp and php because this is a debug copy of an intranet server, which I have to work on.

Comment: have you looked for  [this](http://www.valuehost.ru/en/hosting/about_service/shared/libs/libsphp/)

Comment: @kirgiz_jigit ok ? what should I do with "this" ?

Comment: Click to it :)  I think you cannot avoid zend engine if you need to work with php. But if you are talking about Zend-Framework it won't install during LAMP installation.

Comment: @kirgiz_jigit that was not the question I guess

Comment: @Bongo Could you solve this problem eventually? I'm having the same.

Comment: @Wipster I think we did the same as you answered :) but I am not sure

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and could solve it by simply updating from XDebug 2.7.0 to 2.7.2.